# Library method Tooltip unusable

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I had the idea to learn some Python, but I'm failing because the
code completion and the tooltip do no work as expected - at least for a Java programmer.

I used VSC with the Pyhton extenstion from Microsoft.
Let me show you my problem.

[pyplot_hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlWw9.png)

For me it is not clear that is returns or why I'm able to provide an alpha parameter.
Is it broken or is the intended way of Python?

Comment: what do you mean it doesnt work ?  the image shows that it does work...

Comment: but alpha is nowehere listed as a valid parameter. 
Also the three responses are only shown as Any.

Comment: that could be to do with the documentation of the dunction being poor. For example, the `print` statement shows better help. You can actually view the function definition from the dropdown menu or `f12` key in `vscode`...

Comment: This question is related to the documentation provided by the package, the python extension just gets the documentation, you can submit this issue in the package's github